# scrape the value from a dropdown

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to web scrape the value and text from a dropdown element on a webpage using a combination of Python with selenium and Beautiful Soup.

I am able to get the text but I am not able to get the value through the `get_attribute` command.

When I print the element that I located on the webpage it returns the following content

[image: print(price)]

The print statement that gets it gives the error:

```
None Type object is not callable

price=soup.find("select",{"id":"space-prices"})
print(price)
print(price.text)
print(price.get_attribute('value'))
```

The output for print(price) is

```
<select class="pricing-bar-select" id="space-prices" name="space-prices"><option selected="selected" value="£360">Per Day</option>
<option value="£1,260">Per Week</option>
<option value="£5,460">Per Month</option>
<option value="£16,380">Per Quarter</option>
<option value="£65,520">Per Year</option></select>
```

The URL of the webpage is

https://www.appearhere.co.uk/spaces/north-kensington-upcycling-store-and-cafe

Comment: Sample code to reproduce the error would be helpful.

Comment: Hi @mpaskov . I am new to Stack overflow. I don't know how to format my code and paste it here. sorry for the Inconvenience. Can you please see the hyperlink - value in the question?

Comment: just copy and paste and use ctrl-K to format as code.

Comment: Have a look at the following links [How-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Ya done that and edited my question

Comment: @JulienBernu Thanks for that short-cut key

Comment: @mpaskov Thanks for the document. I will have a look into it as well.

Comment: can you share the url of webpage, Also you want to print values like £1,260 ?

Comment: @thebadguy  , Yes Pretty much I want the output print statement to be something like Per Day :  £126. I am able to get the Per Day through text but the value is remaining as a problem. You actually helped me in some other query as well. Thanks ! I have posted the URL with the question now. Kindly see that

Comment: @Rojo, I have provide my answer,hope it will help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


driver = webdriver.Chrome()
url= "https://www.appearhere.co.uk/spaces/north-kensington-upcycling-store-and-cafe"
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get(url)

content = driver.page_source.encode('utf-8').strip()
soup = BeautifulSoup(content,"html.parser")
price=soup.find("select",{"id":"space-prices"})
options = price.find_all("option")
options1=[y.text for y in options]
values = [o.get("value") for o in options]
for x in range(5):
    print options1[x], values[x].encode('utf8')
driver.quit()
```

It will print

```
Per Day £360
Per Week £1,260
Per Month £5,460
Per Quarter £16,380
Per Year £65,520
```

Hope this is what you want

Comment: Thanks @thebadguy. This is pretty much my requirement.

Answer (score 2):

It's because `get_attribute` seems to be `None`.  It's not a valid attribute of the `prices` object.  So it's not a function that you can call - hence the error.  If you took away the parentheses and just printed `prices.get_attribute` nothing would print, because the value is `None`.

Also, the `<select>` tag doesn't have a "value" attribute in the first place.  What you've done is you've grabbed the `<select>` tag, and all of it's children.  Each child in the `<select>` tag (the `<option>` tags) have a "value" attribute.  If you are trying to get all of the values of all of the `<option>` tags in that `<select>`, then you should do the following:

```
price=soup.find("select",{"id":"space-prices"})

# get all <options> in a list
options = price.find_all("option")

# for each element in that list, pull out the "value" attribute
values = [o.get("value") for o in options]
print(values)
#[u'\xa3360', u'\xa31,260', u'\xa35,460', u'\xa316,380', u'\xa365,520']
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I got the Problem. Your Code Worked.

Comment: Not a problem!  Glad I could help.